# How to display Bootstrap 4 navigation bar links next to each other and floating to the right?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a navigation bar in which the brand logo is on the left, but the navigation bar links are on the right. At the moment, the navbar links are on the right but are displayed on top of each other instead of next to each other:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Peek Solutions</a>
  <div class="navbar-nav justify-content-end">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I've tried to right-align them using `.justify-content-end` following https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/, but so far it's not looking the way I want it. (I've also looked at the [Bootstrap 4 source code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/bca4ceacc79b78e5ddb32715065aec245a636892/dist/css/bootstrap.css) but wasn't able to quickly determine what the issue was).

**Update**

If I use the following snippet,

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Peek Solutions</a>
  <div class="navbar justify-content-end">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

then the positioning is as desired (see https://jsfiddle.net/qxdsam8t/10/) but the color of the links reverts to its default color of blue, instead of the light gray theme color. If I add the class `navbar-nav` to the inner `div`, then the colors go back to the theme colors, but the display is 'stacked' like I started out with. It seems that these properties are 'coupled'; how can I get the colors but not the 'stacking'?

Comment: Your JSFiddle is invalid. It has the line `<div class="navbar justify-content-end">` as opposed to `<div class="navbar-nav justify-content-end">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The menu item stacking happens due to the `.navbar-expand-lg` class. xs/sm/md viewports will stack the menu items since the rendering should be stacked once the collapsed menu view (hamburger menu) is being used. You can see I changed it to `.navbar-expand-sm` to hopefully illustrate this better when running the code snippet (depending on how wide your browser is).

Also, add `.justify-content-between` to the `<nav>` element to right align the nav **or** you can add `.ml-auto` to the `.navbar-nav` `<div>` **or** even use `.w-100` along with `.justify-content-end` to force nav to be full width.

You'll probably want to wrap the `.navbar-nav` element with: `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse"></div>` and include a navbar toggler button, similar to their documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#toggler

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark justify-content-between">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Peek Solutions</a>
  <div class="navbar-nav justify-content-end">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The document you linked states to use either a `<ul>` element or a `<nav>` element.

> Classes are used throughout, so your markup can be super flexible. Use
>   <ul>s like above, or roll your own with say a <nav> element. Because
>   the .nav uses display: flex, the nav links behave the same as nav
>   items would, but without the extra markup.

```
<nav class="nav">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: The navbar generated like this does not float to the right or have the desired colors.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is not good at all. Take a look at bootstrap documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/). To align your nav to right use *"ml-auto"* bootstrap class in *ul* element in your nav. Bootstrap 4 is all about flexbox layout, so you have to be really precise with HTML markup.

Comment: though I would probably prefer the use of <ul>, according to Boostrap documentation, you are able to use <div> structure as well: "And because we use classes for our navs, you can avoid the list-based approach entirely if you like."